# Hypothesis Testing and calculating p-value for Pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas, p-value, hypothesis-test

I want to study the relationship between car accidents and weather temperature.

So, I have a dataset for car accidents that have different attributes related to accidents and weather temperature for when the accidents occurred as follow:
[image]

To study this relationship, I want to formulate my hypothesis as follow:

- H0: There is no relationship between hot weather (greater than 28
  degrees Celsius) and the number of car accidents
- H1: There is a relationship between hot weather (greater than 28
  degrees Celsius)    and the number of car accidents

I am not sure of how to calculate the p-value for the above hypothesis in python. I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

cd = pd.read_csv('Accidents.csv', parse_dates=['DATE'])

hot = cd[cd['Temperature Celsius']>28]
notHot = cd[cd['Temperature Celsius']<=28]

ttest_ind(hot['Temperature Celsius'], notHot['Temperature Celsius'])
```

How do I calculate the p-value for the above hypothesis? is my implementation correct by just getting the records that match my criteria and passing them to ttest-ind or I have to pass all the dataset instead of "notHot"?

or should I summarize the data using a different approach such as the number of accidents in each months compared to targeted weather temperature and perform different statistical test as follow:
[image]

I am a bit lost on how to choose the best statistical test and how to perform it. I am interested in the statistical significance of the effect of temperature on the number of accidents. So, is it better to calculate the statistical significance using the above hypothesis or using regression for example?

Thank you very much.

The sample dataset is available in the following link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WWtihWyUhL1m5Bp094SINTF14_icncnh

Comment: This is not a coding question, but statistical-modeling question. And if you have only data about accidents, you can't check your hypothesis. You need to check the probabilty to have an accident in hot weather in comparison to have an accident in not-hot weather, and without information about non-accidents drives, you don't have probabilities.

Comment: @Aryerez it is difficult to know or get records of accidents that did not happen. So, given the data I have of accidents, how can I measure the significance of hot weather on the number of accidents? Is there a workaround?

Comment: @Aryerez for example is it better to calculate the statistical significance using regression as a workaround? if so, how to do that?

Comment: The only workaround I can think about is getting the part of the time the temperature was over 28, and the part of the time the temperature was under 28 for each day/week/month, and see how many accidents happens for each time unit in hot weather and in not-hot weather. With just the data you have, I can't think of something aduqate.